# mySQL - Compare if values are equal from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a newbie and i'm trying to check if the location in STUDENT table is equal to the location of the QR. Anyone knows how to do this?

**Student TABLE**

```
|Student_ID|Name|Gender|Location|
---------------------------------
| 0118210  |Dex | Male | PJU1/42|
```

**QR Table**

```
|QR_Code|Date Generated|QR_Location|
------------------------------------
|  4747 |   4/6/2018   | PJU1/42   |
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for the lack of information given. Basically i would need to build a backend system using Laravel that would generate a QR CODE. Whenever i generate the QR Code, a unique "QR_CODE" would be generated and insert into the QR Table along side with the "Date Generated" and "QR_Location". So whenever i use my mobile phone to scan the QR Code i would like to check if my current location is equal to the location of the location of the QR_Location.

Hope that this would give u guys some idea of what i am trying to achieve.

Thank you

Comment: how about an inner join?

Comment: There is no problem to be a newbie, we are all in some moment. But explain better what you want to get is not a matter of being a newbie or not. Do you mean with your question that you want to get all the Locations which match in both tables, those which are in one but not in the other one... Do you know what you want to get?

Comment: This is a question with many answers and could very well be used in the examples of support documentation - joins are one of the most important parts of sql - reading up on them would help you greatly in addition to the good answers below.

Comment: They're the same, so, yes. It is. Next!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *plenty* of way to do this. But i would do this as

```
select s.*
from Student s
where exists (select 1 from QR q where s.Location = q.QR_Location);
```